# Trying to update someone's socket programming code written in Swift 3 to Swift 5.2 (Inout expression creates a temporary pointer...)

Tags: swift, sockets, pointers, buffer, inout

The following code originally written in Swift 3, worked without warning in Swift 4.2, gave the warning "Inout expression creates a temporary pointer, but argument #1 should be a pointer that outlives the call to '+'" in Swift 5,  now not compiling in Xcode 12 at all with an error saying "Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred".

```
func readNUInt8(_ n:UInt32) throws -> [UInt8] {
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(n))
        var read = 0
        
        while read < Int(n) {
            
            read += recv(s, &buffer + read, Int(n) - read, 0)
            
            if read <= 0 {
                throw SocketError.recvFailed(Socket.descriptionOfLastError())
            }
        }
        
        if bytesToRead >= UInt32(n) {
            bytesToRead -= UInt32(n)
        }
        
        return buffer
    }
```

I tried to solve this by converting read to UInt8 and appending to buffer before calling recv() function, but the app crashed elsewhere probably because I broke the socket reading by incorrectly storing read bytes like that.

Any suggestions how to correct the above code to read and store the buffer the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by explicitly using .withUnsafeMutableBytes for the buffer, hence changing the function block to the following:

```
func readNUInt8(_ n:UInt32) throws -> [UInt8] {
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(n))
        var read = 0
        
        while read < Int(n) {
            
            var recvResult : ssize_t = 0
            
            // let recvResult = recv(s, &buffer + read, Int(n) - read, 0)

            buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { goPointer in recvResult = recv(s, goPointer.baseAddress! + read, Int(n) - read, 0) }
            read += recvResult
            if read <= 0 {
                throw SocketError.recvFailed(Socket.descriptionOfLastError())
            }
        }
        
        if bytesToRead >= UInt32(n) {
            bytesToRead -= UInt32(n)
        }
        
        return buffer
    }
```